# How can I emulate film in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, film, presets

I've tried so many different websites trying to find cheap lightroom film emulations.

I'd like to achieve looks like these:

[image: example image 1]
[image: example image 2]

Comment: check https://mastinlabs.com/

Comment: Why not just create your own? Anything a preset does within LR you can do yourself by manually adjusting the sliders.

Comment: @Ryan Please see http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/short-answers-as-comments-please-resist-the-urge

Answer (score 4):

There is nice third-party add-on from Google called Nik. It was paid but they released it free. It cooperates nicely with Photoshop and Lightroom.

Black and White: https://www.google.com/nikcollection/products/silver-efex-pro/

Color: https://www.google.com/nikcollection/products/color-efex-pro/

There are several film presets as well as possibility to do things manually.